# Probability of hitting a number

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider a set $S$ of $N$ numbers. Fix a collection $T$ of $N^{\frac{1}{2}}$ numbers. With every trial, we have the freedom to choose $N^{\frac{2}{3}}$ of them at a time without overlapping. My questions are the following.

What is the probability that a given trial will pick atleast one number from the subset $T$?
In general, how many trials should one expect to make before we choose a number from the subset $T$ of $N^{\frac{1}{2}}$ numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected size of the intersection is $N^{1/2} \cdot N^{2/3} / N = N^{1/6}$, and this suggests that it is very likely that you will pick at least one number from the subset $T$. The probability that you will *not* pick any number from the subset $T$ is exactly
$$\frac{\binom{N-N^{1/2}}{N^{2/3}}}{\binom{N}{N^{2/3}}}, $$
which you can estimate to your heart's content using Stirling's approximation:
$$
\begin{align*}
\log \frac{\binom{N-N^{1/2}}{N^{2/3}}}{\binom{N}{N^{2/3}}} &= 
(N-N^{1/2}) \log (N-N^{1/2}) - (N-N^{1/2}-N^{2/3}) \log (N-N^{1/2}-N^{2/3})
\\ &- N\log N + (N-N^{2/3}) \log (N-N^{2/3}) \pm O(\log N) \\ &=
N(1-N^{-1/2}) \log N (1 - N^{-1/2} - O(N^{-1})) \\ &-
N(1-N^{-1/2}-N^{-1/3}) \log N (1-N^{-1/2}-N^{-1/3}-\tfrac{1}{2}N^{-2/3}-N^{-5/6}-O(N^{-1})) \\ &-
N\log N + N(1-N^{-1/3}) \log N (1-N^{-1/3}-\tfrac{1}{2}N^{-2/3}-O(N^{-1})) \pm O(\log N) \\ &=
N\log N (-\tfrac{1}{2} N^{-2/3} - N^{-5/6}) \pm O(\log N) \\ &=
(-\tfrac{1}{2} N^{1/3} - N^{1/6} \pm O(1)) \log N.
\end{align*}
$$
We conclude that the probability is
$$
N^{-(1/2)N^{1/3}-N^{1/6} \pm O(1)},
$$
which is very small. With more effort (using more terms in Stirling's approximation and in the Taylor expansions) we could determine the constant in the exponent, or even get subconstant terms there. A decent CAS should be able to do this calculation automatically, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to convince Wolfram alpha to help here.

Alternatively, you can use [Chernoff's bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) for [negatively dependent random variables](http://www.brics.dk/RS/96/25/BRICS-RS-96-25.pdf). The idea is to have $X_i$ be an indicator for the event that the $i$th member of the subset lies in $T$. While the sequence $X_1,\ldots,X_{N^{2/3}}$ is perhaps not negatively dependent (I'm not sure), the linked article shows that if you sample $N^{2/3}$ points *with replacement*, then the sequence $Y_{i,j}$ is negatively dependent, where $Y_{i,j}$ is the indicator for the event that the $i$th samples point equals the $j$th point in $T$. Sampling with replacement only makes it *easier* to avoid $T$ (this can be argued formally using coupling, for example: whenever you sample the same point twice, in the coupled copy sample a new point; this only increases your chance to hit $T$).

One version of Chernoff's bound that is easy to state is:
$$ \Pr[\sum_{ij} Y_{ij} \leq (1-\delta) \mu] \leq e^{-\delta^2 \mu/2}, $$
where $\mu$ is the expected value of the sum, in our case $N^{1/6}$. Taking $\delta = 1$, we deduce that the probability that we miss $T$ is at most $e^{-N^{1/3}/2}$, which is very small. This bound is almost as good as the one we computed explicitly: the difference is only a $\log N$ factor in the exponent.

If the success probability is $p$, then the expected number of trials is $1/p$, since this is a geometric random variable. Since $p \approx 1$, also $1/p \approx 1$.

Comment: @Turbo While I can do the calculation myself, I believe that so can you. Expand the binomials to factorials, and apply Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @Turbo No, I don't know the answer. I can do the calculation, but since it's your question, it makes more sense for you to do the calculation. That way, next time you won't have to ask anybody for help.

Comment: @Turbo It's not clear that the approximation is justified, and the first equality is just wrong. To be really sure, you should take the logarithm, use Stirling's approximation, and then use some Taylor approximations. It's a bit messy but has a reasonable probability of success.

Comment: $$\binom{a}{b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}\approx\frac{a^a}{b^b(a-b)^{a-b}}\approx\big( \frac{a}{b} \big)^{b}.$$

Comment: @Turbo The approximations only "work" in some circumstances, and in these circumstances it's not so clear that they're justified, since the exponents are rather large.

Comment: brilliant answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Turbo I now added the calculation I had in mind.

Comment: Why do you need $-\tfrac{1}{2}N^{-2/3}-N^{-5/6}-O(N^{-1})$ in the approximation??

Comment: Could you explain your steps further?? How do you get $NlogN(−\frac{1}{2}N^{−2/3}−N^{−5/6})±O(logN)$ in the final step?

Comment: Could I ask what happens if we choose only $N^{\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon}$ numbers instead of $N^{\frac{2}3}$?

Comment: Then the behavior would be quite different. It would make a nice exercise for you.

Comment: I calculated but Chernoff approach gives subexponential trials while other gives polynomial. I was not sure.

Comment: Posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397956/probability-of-hitting-a-number-ib-rare-case

Comment: Also $\mathsf{mathematica}$ seems to converge to a constant around $$0.3678794411714423215955237701614608674458111310317678345078$$ on $\frac{Binomial[N^{3/2}- N^{1/2}, N^{2/2}]}{Binomial[N^{3/2}, N^{2/2}]}$ command. So I am confused here. Is there an easy way to see this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using Stirling's approximation here?

Comment: No I only tried your technique using entropy and chernoff. I do not know to use Stirling's approximation.

Comment: That's an excellent opportunity to learn. Wikipedia has a good description.

Comment: So you think $\mathsf{mathematica}$ is wrong?

Comment: I don't have an opinion on the matter, though usually computer algebra systems are right. If you use Stirling's approximation, you might be able to compute the constant.

Comment: ok I will try and get back. Also http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=.367879 says $e^{-1}$.

Comment: There is an inverse type of questions that is also bothering where I want to touch every number atleast once http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401455/trials-needed-to-hit-all-numbers I tried thinking of the problem, but unable to get a coherent picture.

Comment: Sorry here is link again http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401455/trials-needed-to-hit-all-numbers for inverse type of problem.