# Probability of hitting a number $Ib$ (rare case)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Consider a set $S$ of $N^{3/2}$ numbers. Fix a collection $T$ of $N^{\frac{1}{2}}$ numbers. With every trial, we have the freedom to choose $N^{1-\epsilon}$ of them at a time without overlapping. My questions are the following.

What is the probability that a given trial will pick atleast one number from the subset $T$?
In general, how many trials should one expect to make before we choose a number from the subset $T$ of $N^{\frac{1}{2}}$ numbers?

Relevant: [Probability of hitting a number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1046067/probability-of-hitting-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

It will be simpler to consider the case in which the elements are sampled *with* replacement (this doesn't change the overall picture at all, but simplifies the arguments). The expected intersection of the randomly chosen $N^{1-\epsilon}$ elements with $T$ is then $N^{-\epsilon}$. Since this number is so small, one can conjecture that the probability that the intersection is non-empty is roughly $N^{-\epsilon}$, and so the expected number of trials until hitting $T$ is roughly $N^\epsilon$.

We can also estimate the probability that the intersection is empty:
$$
\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)^{N^{1-\epsilon}} \approx e^{-N^{-\epsilon}} \approx 1 - N^{-\epsilon}.
$$
This confirms our suspicions mentioned above.

So far all we have done are heuristic estimates. But it is not difficult to obtain provable estimates, using Taylor series. We leave these calculations to the reader or to a computer algebra system.

Comment: I tried Stirling's approximation. It gives probability of failure as $1$. So making without replacement (as in question) improves odds of a hit right?

Comment: You probably didn't use enough terms in Stirling's approximation. For $\epsilon > 0$ it shouldn't matter too much whether you're choosing the elements with or without replacement, since even if you choose them with replacement, with high probability the number of unique elements is $\Theta(N^{1-\epsilon})$.

Comment: However why does chernoff bound fail miserably here?

Comment: The success probability in Chernoff's bound is often though of as constant, i.e., bounded away from 0 and 1. In this case it is very close to 0 or 1 (depending on what you count as success). Perhaps a more refined version of the bound would work. In any case, Chernoff's bound is only an upper bound, and is not guaranteed to give a reasonable bound in all cases.

Comment: Why is probability that intersection is empty is $(1-\frac{1}N)^{N^{1-\epsilon}}$?

Comment: Each of the $N^{1-\epsilon}$ numbers hits $T$ with probability $1/N$. Since I assumed that sampling is with replacement, the probability that none of them hit $T$ is $(1-1/N)^{N^{1-\epsilon}}$.

Comment: So for without replacement, is it $(1-\frac{1}N)(1-\frac{2}N)\dots(1-\frac{N^{1-\epsilon}-2}N) (1-\frac{N^{1-\epsilon}-1}N)\approx e^{N^{1-\epsilon}}$?

Comment: @Turbo No, this formula is incorrect. Try again. Don't guess, calculate.

Comment: I do not think $N^\epsilon$ trials is right answer. If I use $N^\epsilon=log N$, I get infinity from mathematica since $$\frac{\binom{N^{3/2}-N^{1/2}}{N/\log N}}{\binom{N^{3/2}}{N/\log N}}\rightarrow1$$ shows up with $N$ being like $10^{19}$.

Comment: I give up. You should try harder solving your problems on your own, without constantly asking for outside help.

Comment: I think I figured out thank you.